# onmouseover error with bootstrap

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I dont know whats causing the error but it is working when i dont use the link of bootsrap.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootsrap.css"/>
```

But when I use this link of bootstrap, mouseover is not working.

What's causing the error what are the solutions in this?

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
<p onmouseover="playSound('<?php echo $audiopath; ?>');">
    <textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="question" readonly style="width:96.8%;text-align:left;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2px;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0;color:#0000ff;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;" >
         <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($r['question'],ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Do you mean boots**t**rap.css?

Comment: Can you check the console output in your browser? Usually this gives valuable information

Comment: thers nothing inside the console ~_~

Comment: IT is working when I remove the bootstrap link.. but when I put on the link <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootsrap.css"/> it is not working

Comment: Perhaps you have an incorrect path to the stylesheet?  I recommend viewing the page source in your browser, and making sure the CSS file is a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: It has a correct path sir. When i removed <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/> link it is working. But when i do put it. IT is not. I dont know what the problem is either

Answer (score 0):

You must add style in p tag

```
style="cursor:hand"
```

Comment: Why you don't close p tag?

Comment: <p style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="playSound('<?php echo $audiopath; ?>');">Play</p>

Comment: because there are still codes after that i just Put the part of it